# Búsqueda y comparación de datos en arrays

Tags: javascript, array, google-apps-script

La idea es, comparar 1 valor string o primer valor dentro de arrays, dentro de otro array principal, según el resultado hacer referencia al array interno correspondiente y usar sus valores.

En Javascript, o Google Apps Script.

Tengo un array de datos DATA, dentro de este array tengo otros arrays cada uno con sus datos particulares su estructura es similar:
3 datos:
1º ID opcional, puede esar vacio, ser un numero o un texto,
2º Nombre de usuario
3º ID del sistema.

```js
DATA = [[, "PEPE", "3567890987654322234567"], ["12", "JUAN", "100933185706735930958"], ["12", "ALFREDO", "107060714183137539122"], ["23", "ALEX", "1005930958"]]
```

Para un caso normal uso esto:

```js
var fichas = [123456789,1234567890,1234567890,087654,987345,3450987,34560987321,];
var fichaUnica = 123456789;

var cuenta = 0;
var posicion = fichas.indexOf(fichaUnica);
  while ( posicion !== -1 ) {
      cuenta++;
      posicion = fichas.indexOf(fichaUnica,posicion+1);
  } 
  if (cuenta === 1)
  {
  }
  else if (cuenta > 1)
  {
  Logger.log('El ID se repite');
  }
  else
  {
  Logger.log('El ID no se encuentra en la lista');
  }
```

Como puedo hacer lo mismo pero con el array de arrays comparando el 1 valor y hacer referencia a los otros valores del array devuelto.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina. +1 por plantear tu problema de manera correcta.

Answer (score 0):

La opción mas adecuada entiendo que sería `.filter()` pero si quisieras guardar otro tipo de información en lugar de los elementos repetidos podrías usar `.reduce()`:

```js
const data = [
  ["", "PEPE", "3567890987654322234567"],
  ["12", "JUAN", "100933185706735930958"],
  ["12", "ALFREDO", "107060714183137539122"],
  ["23", "ALEX", "1005930958"],
  ["", "PEPE", "3567890987654322234567"]
];

const numero = "3567890987654322234567";

const res = data.reduce((p, c, i) => {
  if (c.includes(numero)) p.push({
    posicion: i
  });
  return p;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Vale creo entender lo que hace este trozo de código, pero no me va a funcionar en Apps Script .