# ¿Como obtener un dato de un formulario, otorgando dos parámetros en google spreadsheet con HTML y google script?

Tags: javascript, html, formularios, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Soy nuevo en Google Apps Scripts.

En la universidad donde realizo mi apoyo necesito realizar una página HTML donde el profesor de manera interna le otorguemos los resultados de su postulación o a los aspirantes de ingreso los resultados por medio de la "CURP" y su "email", se muestren todos los datos si fueron aceptados o no visualizando estos mismos criterios en la HTML.

Este es mi HTML con el formulario:

[image: este es la HTML]

Este es el HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <?!= include('page-css'); ?>
    </head>
    <body>
  
      <h4>Resultados Aplicadores </h4>
      
 <div class="container">
 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="CURP" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="CURP">CURP</label>
        </div>
      </div>
               
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="Email" type="email" class="validate">
          <label for="Email">Email</label>
        </div>
      </div>    
    
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input disabled id="status" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="status" class="active">STATUS:</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input disabled id="sede" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="sede">SEDE:</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input disabled id="aplicador" type="text" class="validate">
          <label for="aplicador">TIPO DE APLICADOR:</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      
        <div class="row">
             <button id="btn" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="btn">Consultar<i class="material-icons right">consultar</i>
             </button>
        </div>
      
      
      
     
     
     
      </div> <!----------CERRAMOS CONTENEDOR--->
      
      
      
        
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
      <?!= include('page-js'); ?>
                
  </body>
</html>
```

Este es el código de mi script:

```js
<script>
      
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",getstatus);

     });   
      
      
       var InfoCURP = document.getElementById("CURP");

           
       function getstatus(){
       
              var CURP = InfoCURP.value;
      
              var statusinfo = document.getElementById("CURP").value;
              
              if(getstatus.length === 18){
              google.script.run.withSuccessHadler(updateCURP).getcurpstatus(statusinfo);
               }
          }      
       function updateCURP(CURP) {      
              document.getElementById("status").value = CURP;
              M.updateTextFields();
             
      
      }
      
      
    </script>
```

Y este es el código de secuencia de comandos (gs) de Google Apps Script:

```js
function doGet(e){
     return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page").evaluate();
}


  function getcurpstatus(statusinfo){
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lLum3hc5T7whhDvEEYSAAb9PhL8HRV8l7QsuUNjf73w/edit#gid=0";
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName("basecurp");
    var data = ws.getDataRange().getValues();
    
    var curplist = data.map(function(r){ return r[0]; });
     var statuslist = data.map(function(r){ return r[1]; });
     
     var position = curplist.indexOf(statusinfo);
         if(position > -1){
             return statuslist[position];
         }else{
             return 'CURP no existente';
   }
    
  
  }
  
  function include(filename){
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(filename).getRawContent()
  
  }
```

Tal como lo tengo ahora no es lo que estoy buscando, ya que aún no he podido tomar el segundo parámetro, el correo y colocar los resultados, " STATUS", "SEDE", "TIPO de APLICADOR", dando click en "consultar"

[image]

Esta es la base donde necesito obtener los resultados a mostrar:

[image]

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] y a [tag:google-apps-script]. Al hacer preguntas aquí procura incluir sólo lo necesario para entender lo que estas preguntando (evita saludos, agradecimientos, firmas, lemas, etc.)

Comment: Falta que indiques que es lo que has intentado para obtener los parámetros que te hacen falta y/o lo que has buscado/investigado al respecto.

Comment: Gracias he intentado con esto realizar una busqueda de los valores "CURP" e "email" obtener los parametros de "Status", "Sede" y "tipo de Aplicador" dentro del spreadsheet para mostrar los resultados al aspirante, y lo mismo eh intentado con la funcion de getDisplayValues() sin embargo no se bien como desarrollar el codigo para que este funcione de manera correcta

Answer (score 0):

Para tomar el email debes hacer los mismo que haces con el CURP

```
document.getElementById("CURP").value
```

sólo cambia el "CURP" por el Id correspondiente.

Luego en

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHadler(updateCURP).getcurpstatus(statusinfo);
```

envía los dos parámetros, por ejemplo (estoy cambiando los nombres de las variables)_

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHadler(updateCURP).getcurpstatus(curp, email);
```

lo anterior implica que modifiques la función `getcurpstatus` para recibir los dos parámetros.

Luego para encontrar el registro que coincida con esos dos valores puedes usar [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Relacionado

- [¿Cómo filtrar un Array 2D usando dos criterios de coincidencia exacta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/238667/65)
- [Búsqueda y comparación de datos en arrays](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/300364/65)

Comment: Gracias @Rubén intentare modificar los datos como me indicas y te doy mis comentarios